# How to "get back to root path" in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, url

I am very new and inexperienced to Flask and web development. This is probably a duplicate of another question but I cannot find the answer or question I am looking for.

Basically I have a page with a form that is used to get query parameters from a database. I list those entries and make a link in one of the fields to go into detailed view (and have a delete button). The url for the form would be: `127.0.0.1:5000/form-page`. When going into detailed view I currently do it as `127.0.0.1:5000/form-page/data_1/data/2`. When I then press a button for another link, say to go to index, I don't end up in `127.0.0.1:5000/index` but `127.0.0.1:5000/form-page/data_1/data/2/index` instead.

-EDIT-

What I used which didn't work was

```
<div class="topnav">
    <a href="index"><h1>Page title</h1></a>
</div>
```

meanwhile the following works

```
<div class="topnav">
    <a href={{ url_for("index") }}><h1>Page title</h1></a>
</div>
```

-END EDIT-

My question is: How do I get back to "the root" url from pressing buttons

I know using `/value_1/value_2` might be the wrong convention for passing data. I've seen `?key=value` but don't know how to implement that either or when it is correct to use one or the other.

Comment: Add `HTML` template snippet example that you were using and where you found the issue so other would see what was the cause of it. Other then that it's all good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In writing this question I realized my error.

In the HTML template I had just written the "name" of the url or page. For example `<a href="lookup_form">Lookup form</a>` instead of `<a href={{ url_for("lookup_form") }}><h1>Lookup form</h1></a>`.

Hopefully this can be of help to someone.

@moderators: feel free to to mark this as a duplicate. I would love this question and answer to be better formulated by someone who knows the lingo and subject better.

Comment: Just mark your answer as accepted so it would be seen here.

Comment: @simkus I have to wait two days first.

Comment: Ok, but do it so others would see instantly ;)